# Getting most accurate "current pace" when running with iPhone GPS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, accelerometer

When running with RunKeeper or Nike+ the current pace jumps a lot (shows anything from 4-5min/km when running at 4.30/km, while the overall distance and average pace is quite good.

I started developing my own running app and noticed that they are probably using the data straight from CLLocationManager. Here is my Swift 3 code that gets similar results to Nike+ for current pace.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    for location in locations {

        print("GOT LOCATION \(location)")

        if location.horizontalAccuracy < 20 {

            if self.locations.count > 0 {

                distance += location.distance(from: self.locations.last!)
            }
            self.locations.append(location)
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to get a better current pace? Current pace can be extended to being "last 30 seconds" if that would help. The error margin should be maximum +- 5 sec/km (or as small as possible)

Answer (score 1):

PROGRESS UPDATE

I'm using the following settings and are testing the code when running using both Nike+ simultaneously on my phone, and a Garmin Fenix 3 watch with the Styrd footpod (which is said to be super accurate).

```
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
_locationManager.activityType = .fitness
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
```

Then in locationmanager:

```
if location.horizontalAccuracy < 40 {
    distance += location.distance(from: savedLocations.last!)
}
```

Using this code i get 20% more distance compared to Nike+ and Garmin.

```
My code 12.3 km
Nike + 10.01 km (running simultaneously on the phone, getting the same GPS updates)
Garmin 9.75 km
```

These ratios was kept during the whole run, so when Nike+ logged 5km, my code logged 6km.

Since the GPS location often has a low (actual) horizontalAccuracy, some extra operations should be needed to get really accurate distance. I wanted to see what would happen if I simply adjusted the ratio to align with Nike+, ie 10/12,3 = 0.81 ratio.

So I changed the code to

```
distance += location.distance(from: savedLocations.last!) * 0.81
```

and ran the same 10 km yesterday. This time I got the results:

```
My code 9.04 km (or 11.16 if I wouldn't have used * 0.81)
Nike+ 10.00 km
Garmin 9.66 km
```

So, this time the ratio was actually to 0.9 than 0.81. So there must be something else that Nike+ does.

The most depressing fact is that my code logged 12.3 km the first time and 11.16 km the second time.

Ideas:

increase (lower the value of) the required accuracy.

```
if location.horizontalAccuracy < 40 {
```

However I needed 40 for it to work well in the city with my iPhone 7+
Clearly I'd rather get no update than one that is 40m wrong

set distanceFilter to for example 10

```
_locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
```

Both these ideas affects the number of location updates that will be generated. This in turn will make the runner seem to go more "in a straight line", less jitter. This will make the distance shorter which is what we want. But is it a well balanced accuracy for the average running trail? Small turns will not get picked up. Will it be more accurate that the * 0.81 approach?

I will probably try today with

```
_locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
if location.horizontalAccuracy <= 20
```

and see where that takes me.

Comment: No sorry. I gave up. Do you have any ideas?